# What word can I use to describe a design that is focused on function as opposed to form?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

A product is designed in such a way that it is highly functional but the form is entirely reliant on the components pre-existing form - for example an anglepoise lamp's form is shaped by the springs, metal structure and lampshape. There is no additional ornamentation.

Comment: Anything wrong with *functional*?

Comment: Compare *functional* vs. *aesthetic* design.

Comment: Minimalist? Clean ?

Comment: There's always ["form follows function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_follows_function).  See also ["functionalism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functionalism_(architecture)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest **[Utilitarian](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/utilitarian)**

> adj.
>   1. of, pertaining to, or characterized by utility.
>   2. designed for or concerned with utility or usefulness rather than beauty, etc.

This expresses more of an idea that the [form arises from the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_follows_function) than that it arises from the components available. If the over-riding influence of the components is what you particularly want to express then **[Unornamented](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unornamented)** may be appropriate

> Adj.  
>  1. unornamented - lacking embellishment or
>   ornamentation eg *"a plain hair style"; "unembellished white walls"; "functional
>   architecture featuring stark unornamented concrete"*

Comment: _Utilitarian_ is what I thought too. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I will make something up for you.

> The form is driven by the original shape of the component parts

i.e.

*a component-driven* design